# How to Return Multiple Responses in Chatbot?

Tags: python, flask, chatbot

this is my source code iam getting a single response,help me to get multiple responses in chatbot...i have tried many different ways but nothing works ..help me out to solve this problem
suppose if i post a question it should return the matching multiple responses from the database and return those answers

```
from chatterbot import ChatBot
from flask_restful import Resource
from chatterbot.trainers import ListTrainer
from flask import request
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
from flask import json
from flask import jsonify
chatbot = ChatBot("Training Example",

storage_adapter='chatterbot.storage.SQLStorageAdapter',
                database_uri = 
"mysql://kiran:kiran@localhost/chatbot",
              logic_adapters=[
                {
                    'import_path': 'chatterbot.logic.BestMatch'
                },
                {
                    'import_path': 'chatterbot.logic.LowConfidenceAdapter',
                    'threshold': 0.65,
                    'default_response': ''
                }
            ])

chatbot.set_trainer(ListTrainer)

chatbot.train([
"Hi there!",
"Hello"])
dd= ["hey","whats up","hello"]

chatbot.train(dd)



class Chatbott(Resource):
    def __init__(self):
        pass


    def get(self):
        return("hey")


def post(self):
    try:
        a = request.get_json()
        name = a['name']
        if a:
            response = chatbot.get_response(name)
            if response !='     ':
                return response.text
            else:
                dd.append(a)
                print(dd)
                return("tiger zinda heeey")




    except (KeyboardInterrupt,SystemExit):
        print("\n Your loop has been closed . ")
```

Comment: There is one chatterbot future plan [chatform](https://github.com/gunthercox/ChatterBot/wiki/Chat-Forms)  and I don't think `gunthercox` or any other person working for that issue. But always you can create your own custom adapter for this specific use-case.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use websockes .For exemple you can use flask-socketio